# Python function for calculating mean value of specific colum in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, iris-dataset

I'm new to Python and trying to create a function that calculate and return the mean value of a specific column, 
without using Python packs or  dataframe fucntions.
**I'm not allowed to use dataframe,series or implementation of pandas.**

**But I'm allowed to use sum,min,max of dataframe and series**

After searching for information I still can't do it right.

this is what i got so far:

```
def calc_column_mean(dataframe, colName):
   mean_value = 0 
   for col in dataframe: 
      mean_value+=col[colName](int) 
   return mean_value
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use pandas dataframe functions? They're much faster than other alternatives typically.

Comment: It's only for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to loop through dataframes is using iterrows, which returns an index / dataframe tuple:

```
def calc_column_mean(dataframe, colName):
    mean_value = 0
    for index, row in df['colname'].itterrows():
        mean_value += row['colname']
    return mean_value
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm not allowed to use  dataframe,series or implementation of pandas, so I'm guessing I can't use "itterows()" . I'm allowed to use  sum,min,max of dataframe and series .

Comment: Thats important information that you should include in your question...